# Should gcc warn when an integral enum that evaluates to 0 is used as a pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

The following program compiles with no warnings (which is undesirable, because omitting the array index on lines 19 and 21 effectively destroys the array).  If you compile with -D CHECK_NONZERO, you will see that line 23 will not compile without a warning, as the enum BBB evaluates to 1 where AAA and aaa evaluate to 0.

It appears that if an enum evaluates to 0, gcc will seamlessly cast it to a NULL pointer.

Should this be considered a bug?

EDIT:  I don't think I was as clear as I could have been about what I perceive to be the issue.  It seems to me there would be no harm in type-checking the enum for warning purposes *before* resolving the enum to its constant value, but this is not how gcc works at the moment.  However, I'm not sure if this is worthy of a bug report or feature request to the gcc project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    AAA,
    BBB,
} alpha_e;

enum {
    aaa,
    bbb,
};

int main(void) {
    alpha_e *alpha_array = malloc(sizeof(*alpha_array) * 2);
    alpha_array[0] = AAA;
    alpha_array[1] = BBB;
    printf("1: alpha_array[0] == %u, alpha_array[1] == %u\n", alpha_array[0], alpha_array[1]);
    alpha_array = AAA;
    printf("2: alpha_array[0] == %u, alpha_array[1] == %u\n", alpha_array[0], alpha_array[1]);
    alpha_array = aaa;
#ifdef CHECK_NONZERO
    alpha_array = BBB;
#endif
    return 1;
}
```

gcc -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
```

Comment: I'm trying to think of a context in which setting a pointer to *any* `enum` value would be a good idea and not having a lot of luck. Anyone?

Comment: While an enum with value 0 is a valid NULL pointer constant per the standard and gcc doesn't need to produce a diagnostic, it seems that it might be sensible to have a waring that can be enabled/disabled.  By default VC++ 2010 produces the following warning: `warning C4047: '=' : 'alpha_e *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'`

Answer (score 5):

Any integral constant expression that evaluates to 0 should be considered to be a null pointer. I think an enum value is considered constant - it's not a value that you can change.

It is not legal to set a pointer to any other integer value.

Comment: Yes - an enumeration constant is an integral constant expression.

Comment: just don't call it NULL pointer, it is null pointer. NULL has a very specific meaning in the context of C.

Comment: gcc also accepts the following: `0`, `5-5`, `<any variable> * 0`

Answer (score 0):

The integer literal `0` is a null pointer constant.

> (C99, 6.3.2.3p3 Pointers): "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant."

```
int *p = 0;   // p is a null pointer
```

> (C99, 6.3.2.3p3) "If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."

Answer (score 0):

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.<sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
> to a pointer to any object or function.
> 4 Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null pointer of that type.
> Any two null pointers shall compare equal.
> 5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
> entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.<sup>67)</sup>
> ...
>
> ---
>
> 66) The macro NULL is defined in <stddef.h> (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.
> 67) The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
> be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.

So, not a bug.

Comment: The question is not *"is [this code]  buggy"* but *"should [the compiler] warn about [this code]"* which is a bit subjective but presumably turns on the amount of possible damage and the (non-)existence of good reasons to write such code.

Comment: @dmckee: To me, the language above is pretty clear; no diagnostic is necessary.  Enumeration constants are integer constant expressions with type `int`.  An enumeration constant that evaluates to 0 in a pointer context is exactly the same thing as the literal `0`.

Comment: @John: Indeed, if the compiler should warn about this, then it should probably also warn about things like `int *p = !1;` or `int *z = 42-42;`